# React hook caches data over reusing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a hook to work with URL and Local Storage. This hook is called `useListFunctions` and this is the code:

```
const useListFunctions = (entityType) => {

    const filterOperator = {
        containing: 'containing',
        equalTo: 'equalTo',
        greaterThan: 'greaterThan',
        greaterThanOrEqualTo: 'greaterThanOrEqualTo',
        in: 'in',
        lessThan: 'lessThan',
        lessThanOrEqualTo: 'lessThanOrEqualTo',
        notEqualTo: 'notEqualTo',
        notIn: 'notIn'
    }

    const extractFilters = array => array
        .filter(([key, value]) => {
            const operator = value && value.split('_')[0]
            return operator && Object.keys(filterOperator).map(i => i.toLowerCase()).includes(operator?.toLowerCase())
        })
        .map(([key, value]) => {
            return {
                property: key,
                operator: value && value.split('_')[0],
                value: value && value.split('_')[1]
            }
        })

    const extractQueryStringFilters = () => extractFilters(Array.from(new URLSearchParams(document.location.search)))

    const extractLocalStorageFilters = () => {
        const entries = Array.from(Object.entries(window.localStorage))
            .filter(i => i[0].startsWith(entityType))
            .map(i => [i[0].replace(`${entityType}_`, '').replace(`${entityType}_`, ''), i[1]])
        return extractFilters(entries)
    }

    const extractQueryStringFilter = property => extractQueryStringFilters().find(i => i.property === property)

    const extractLocalStorageFilter = property => extractLocalStorageFilters().find(i => i.property === property)

    const extractFilter = property => {
        const queryFilter = extractQueryStringFilter(property)
        if (queryFilter) {
            return queryFilter
        }
        const localStorageFilter = extractLocalStorageFilter(entityType, entityType, property)
        if (localStorageFilter) {
            return localStorageFilter
        }
        return null
    }

    return {
        extractFilter,
        extractFilters,
        extractLocalStorageFilter,
        extractLocalStorageFilters,
        extractQueryStringFilter,
        extractQueryStringFilters,
    }
}

export default useListFunctions
```

It works fine when I load the page. But when I change the route between components (lists), then it seems that it has cached the previous results.

For example, in my `Customers.jsx` list I use it like:

```
const { extractQueryStringFilters } = useListFunctions('Customer')
const filters = extractQueryStringFilters()
```

And it works just greate for `/customers?age=greaterThan_40` the first time.

Then I move to the list of orders, and then back to customers via menu (routing) and the second time the `filters` is an empty array, while the URL is not changed.

What can be wrong here? How can I remove this bug?

Comment: btw your code is not a hook (since it makes no use of useState / useEffect), but a plain function. The problem must be elsewhere ^^

Comment: It seems like the issue might be related to how the useListFunctions hook handles the extraction of filters from the URL and local storage. One possible reason for the filters being empty upon returning to the Customers list could be that the extraction functions aren't correctly capturing the filters or they might be influenced by the state change between components.

Comment: @moonwave99 There is no requirement for custom React hooks to use the `useState` or `useEffect` hooks. And all hooks are plain functions, just with special rules what they are named and when/how they are called.